# SQL and ASP.NET Issues with search

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server

I have 5 - 6 checkboxes with these values:

```
100
200
300
400
500
600
```

These are the values of my dropdown menu, then I use jquery and put what the user selected in an Array and use ajax to send this Array to my ASP.NET API Controller. In my array there can be multiple items (100, 300, 500, 600)

In my API I am using the min (minus 100) and max of the array to filter results in my database table.

What I have here works well:

```
sql += " AND ec.price > " + (Convert.ToInt32(id.price.Min()) - 100).ToString() 
      + " AND ec.price < " + id.price.Max();
```

However when someone selects 600, its really 500+ I am trying to get everything over 500 like so:

```
sql += " AND ec.price > " + (Convert.ToInt32(id.price.Max()) - 100).ToString();
```

Now when I select 100, 200, 400 and 600 I am expecting to get everything between 100 - 400 and everything 500 +

My problem is I don't know how to apply this code, how do I know what the 500+ is?  What is the best way to get my expected results.

Comment: Don't concatenate strings to form your queries. Use parameterized queries to avoid SQL injection attacks.

Comment: You need to read about, understand and start using parameterized queries. The way you have built this indicates you are extremely vulnerable to sql injection. Using parameterized queries will likely fix the issue you are dealing with also.

Comment: What about rather adding 9999999 to the last record of the array before this code and then use a SQL >arrayindex AND <arrayindex+1.  500 will be 500-600 and 600 will be 600-999999

Comment: @AnthonyHorne I like to, can you put it in an answer with a clear example, I am so tired I can barley see and I need this done.